# How to change string in already shape of table to dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have copied a text in the shape of table. Is there a way that I can transform this kind of string to pandas dataframe?

```
'ColA      ColA_weights      ColB   ColB_weights
0  0.038671            1073  1.859599             1
1  20.39974           57362  10.59599             1
2  10.29974            5857  2.859599             1
3  5.040000            1288  33.39599             1
4  1.040000            1064  7.859599             1'
```

- 

Comment: split it on newlines and then on tabs or space, I'd guess.

Comment: `pd.read_clipboard` works like charm for this if it's copied to your clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas-read-csv) with separator as `\s+`. Since the function require file path or buffer to operate, you can wrap the string with `StringIO` which [creates a in-memory text buffer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO).

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from io import StringIO
>>>
>>> source = """
... ColA      ColA_weights      ColB   ColB_weights
... 0  0.038671            1073  1.859599             1
... 1  20.39974           57362  10.59599             1
... 2  10.29974            5857  2.859599             1
... 3  5.040000            1288  33.39599             1
... 4  1.040000            1064  7.859599             1
... """
>>>
>>> df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(source), sep='\s+')
>>> df
        ColA  ColA_weights       ColB  ColB_weights
0   0.038671          1073   1.859599             1
1  20.399740         57362  10.595990             1
2  10.299740          5857   2.859599             1
3   5.040000          1288  33.395990             1
4   1.040000          1064   7.859599             1
>>> df.shape
(5, 4)
```